# iPhone keyboard doesn't appear when entering a UITextField

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

This has to be some kind of newbie blunder that I just can’t see, and I’d be grateful for hints as to what to check or where to look.

I've followed an iPhone tutorial that has a UITextField, making sure I connected the IBOutlet for the text field, and it seems to compile properly (no errors or warnings). But when I run it under the simulator, and click in the field, I don’t get the keyboard, so I can’t enter anything into the field.

I’ve tried searching the site for similar questions, and all I’ve found is a few questions where the developer is trying to set up some complex UI with multiple controllers, and one that seemed to be the same issue, but the original poster simply said that he solved it by starting a new project and porting the code over. I’d like to find an actual solution, so I don’t have to try randomly rebuilding projects when this issue comes up again.

Thanks!

Comment: having the same problem, i have 4 apps already on the AppStore and this is the first time i see this! Is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 17):

Just to cover all your bases when troubleshooting this, make sure it's not the iOS Simulator that's causing this. I wasn't seeing the keyboard appear when entering a UITextView as well and it turns out the simulator allows you to toggle between displaying the virtual keyboard and just having you use your laptop's keyboard.

You toggle between the two via:

`Hardware` > `Keyboard` > `Toggle Software Keyboard`

or press **Cmd + K**.

(my source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24401535/1700540)

So make sure you didn't mistakenly toggle the simulator to only use your physical keyboard! ... like I had

Comment: The hardware keyboard seems to get checked when the simulator is selected and I enter cmd-K thinking I'm clearing the Xcode temps.  Instead the simulator captures the cmd-K and turns on the hardware keyboard.  Entering it again in the simulator or using the menu option from the simulator  "Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard" as stated above turns it off.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure parent containers have **User Interaction Enabled** checked. It is not sufficient for the individual controls to have this checked. The **UIView** can inadvertently get this deselected.

One thing you should check is to make sure the containing view (the **UIView** that contains all the controls), which is the View icon in Interface Builder nib viewer, has **User Interaction Enabled** checked. If the parent container doesn't have this checked, even if the individual controls do, you will see this behavior.

Comment: Thanks! My view had User Interaction Enabled unchecked. I'm working through the APress book, and I unchecked that for the View when I should have made sure it was unchecked for the Image View I added.

Answer (score 3):

What is the delegate for the UITextField connected to? Have you made sure that the delegate functions, particularly `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`
 is returning the right thing (in this case YES)?

Comment: The tutorial doesn't ask for a connection to a delegate, just one to an IBOutlet in the view controller.  I've run through another tutorial that also has a UITextField without a delegate, simply connected to the view controller's IBOutlet, and that one worked.  

If it's any help, the tutorial I'm having difficulty with is from "Beginning iPhone 3 Development" by Mark and LaMarche.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is anyone else's problem but I was using a TextField in a TabBar controller displayed modally and I added the shake gesture in my main view controller.  This unfortunately meant I was setting [self becomeFirstResponder] in the viewDidLoad.  In that case when my modal view displayed it was not becoming the first responder and hence the keyboard did not display.

To fix it I added [self resignFirstResponder] just prior to calling the modal display and all is well once more!  Yay (only took five days to figure that out).

Answer (score 1):

Basicly the only thing you need to do is declare the text field in the .h

`IBOutlet UITextField *textField`

then declare with same name in the property

`@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;`

then make sure you synthesize in the .m

`@synthesize textField;`

then you have to link the field in the interface builder