# Missing keyboard on iOS8 simulator?

Tags: keyboard, simulator, ios8, xcode6

I'm checking my app against iOS8 in the simulator and one thing that puzzles me is that when I tap on a UITextField or UITextView the keyboard doesn't appear on the screen! I can still enter text with my hardware keyboard. Also, if the input element has a inputAccessoryView, that view is shown on the bottom of the screen. So everything works as expected except that the keyboard is not appearing on the screen.
This is valid for all input elements throughout the app.
I don't use the new feature for custom keyboard.

Checked the Settings - don't see anything that can help.

I know XCode6 is still a beta but this seems too obvious problem to be a bug (or is it!?)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In the iOS Simulator menu select:

`Hardware` > `Keyboard` > `Toggle Software Keyboard`

or press **Cmd + K**.

The `Connect Hardware Keyboard` option in the same menu has to be enabled.

Comment: Please, provide some explanation about this solution. Use proper formatting. This kind of answers (low quality) are not too welcome here.

Comment: Looks like it's an options for testing external hardware keyboard, and I pressed it's shortcut(cmd-k) accidentally.

Comment: wow, must've pressed cmd+k by accident ... what a life-saver this thread is :D THANKS!!!

Comment: Apple is driving me crazy with things like this!!! I was 2 hours debugging my code and it was this...

Comment: @FreelanceAr This is discussed in the iOS Simulator documentation and the Xcode release notes, and it's in a pretty obvious (IMO) location in the menus.  Is there a way to make this more obvious or better documented?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia - what's not obvious is why suddenly the keyboard is not present in the first place. It seems odd that with the advent of Xcode6 a number of people are accidentally hitting cmd+k. I, for one, am quite certain that I didn't.

Comment: The simulator app used to have an option to enable this behavior.  We have now made it on by default and removed the previous hacky input behavior (trying to proxy hardware events to keyboard touches) because that approach was no longer viable for the new iOS keyboard model (eg 3rd Party Keyboards)

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be bug in iOS 8. There are two fix to this problem:

1. Toggle between simulator keyboard and MacBook keyboard using **[Command+K]** shortcut key.
2. Reattach keyboard to simulator:

   a. Open Simulator

   b. Select **Hardware -> Keyboard**

   c. Uncheck and then check '**Connect Hardware Keyboard**'

[image: Screenshot for step 2]

OR simply press **[Shift + Command + K] shortcut key**

Comment: The hardware keyboard seems to get checked when the simulator is selected and the I enter command-K thinking I'm clearing the Xcode temps.  Instead it the simulator captures the cmd-K and turns on the hardware keyboard.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue and i resolved by doing following steps

1) Select the iOS Simulator

2) Goto Hardware in menu (top Left)

3) Select Keyboard

4) Uncheck the "Connect Hardware Keyboard" option

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to **disable** "**Slow Animations**" which can be found under "Debug" -> "Slow Animations".

For me, that permanently fixes the issue.

Shortcut is: **CMD + T**